# Another Rails DB Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Supposed I have table "table A" consisting of "colA","colB" and "id", then I create another table "table B" consisting of "colC", "colD", and "id". Then I add reference

```
class AddColToTableA < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :TableA, :colC, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

then that will create another column in table A under the name "table_B_id".
My questions are

1. How do you add default value of table_B_id column so that it is the same as table A's id?
2. If I create a new record in table A, how do I automatically add a new record in table B too? with the table B's ID = table_A_id?

Comment: `table_B_id` is set as foreign key, they are not there to hold any random value.. At max you can keep there as `NULL` and this is the default. For any NON NULL values, those has to be a valid id of the table B that exists.. What you asked is not the problem, but I can tell there is a problem and you are trying to solve that problem with the default value.. What is the actual problem?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the relationship between A and B?